# how to assign values to list type class variable?

Tags: c#

I am working on a module to create event in google calendar so i want to make the json file but please tell me about the following problem.
How can i give value to email of EmailAddress Class?
My View Model Class is:

```
public class CreateJson
    {
        public EventTime end { get; set; }
        public EventTime start { get; set; }
        public string summary { get; set; }
        public List<EmailAddress> attendees { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventTime
    {
        public string dateTime { get; set; }
        public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmailAddress
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
    }


My Controller Class:
 CreateJson objCreateJson = new CreateJson()
            {
                summary = summary,
                end = new EventTime()
                {
                    dateTime =endtime,
                    timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
                },
                start = new EventTime()
                {
                    dateTime = starttime,
                    timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
                },
                attendees =
                {
                   ???????
                }
            };
```

How can i give value to email of EmailAddress Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax:

```
attendees = new List<EmailAddress>()
{
    new EmailAddress(...),
    new EmailAddress(...),
    new EmailAddress(...),
    ...
}
```